# JS How to append to an array with multiple dictionaries with the same keys and different values w/o dictionary being overwritten by latest dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, updating

Am making a working memory game, Dual N' Back on JS - the premise is a function which generates a dictionary of cube attributes, appends these cube attributes to a list of previous cubes in order that the player ascertains if the latest cube matches a cube X steps back in the game.

Right now the Cubegenerator() function returns a Cube with differing attributes ok - the issue I am having is with the var Cubetracker = [] which lists all the Cubes that have previously been generated. Each time a Cube is generated and appended to this list as a dictionary, all entries in the Cubetracker are overwritten by this one dictionary.

Any ideas as to solving the overwriting issue? Thanks for your help!

```
  
var Cube = {
    "dimensions":"1",
    "colour":"2",
    "sound":"3",
    "motion":"4"};    
    
//History of cubes generated for n-back comparison    
var Cubetracker = [];


//Gathering input from number buttons?
//.value property?
//document.getElementById("rp").value;

var rp, nb, sp;
rp = document.getElementById("rp").value;
nb = document.getElementById("nb").value; 
sp = document.getElementById("sp").value;

//Takes inputs from screen 
var game_settings = {"reps":rp,"nback":nb,"speed":sp};    

    
   
function Cubegenerator(){
    
    
  //Let's try encapsulating this within another function for ease of use
    
    function Repeatprob(rprob){
    var rc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (rprob >= rc){
        return true
    }
    return false
    }
    
    var rpyn = Repeatprob(game_settings["nback"]);
    
    if (Cubetracker.length - 1 > 0 && Cubetracker.length - game_settings["nback"] > 0 && rpyn == true){
    alert("You can take the cube from Cubetracker as a repeat cube");
    var rCube = Cubetracker.length - game_settings["nback"];
    var reCube = Cubetracker[rCube];
    Cubetracker.push(reCube);    
    return reCube;     
    }
    
    
    //var Cubetrl = (Cubetracker.length) - //1; 
    //if (Cubetrl - game_settings["nback"] > 0){
    //    var prci = (Cubetracker.length-1) - game_settings["nback"];
    //    var lastc = Cubetracker[prci];
    //    Cubetracker.push(lastc);
    //    return Cubetracker[lastc];
    //                }}
    
    var Dimensions = [];
    //dimensions creator
    var z_pos = "";
    var z_seed = "";
    var defzpos = 50;
    
    for (var i = 0; i< 2; i++)
    {Dimensions.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) - (Math.random() * 300)))}
    
    for (i = 0; i < Dimensions.length; i++){
    var ni = (Dimensions[i]).toString();
    ni += "px";
    Dimensions[i] = ni;
    }
    var z_seed = Math.floor(defzpos * Math.random(1,10));
    var z_seed = z_seed.toString() + "px";
    var z_pos = [z_seed,z_seed];
    
    Dimensions.push(z_pos);
    
    
    var Colour = [];
    var rbgco = "";
    //dimensions creator
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {Colour.push(Math.floor(Math.random(1,10) * 256));
    }
    var rgbco = Colour.toString();
    var rgbco = "RGB(" + rgbco + ")";
    Colour = rgbco;

    
    var Sound = [];
    //sound creator
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {Sound.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));}
        
    var Motion = [];
    //motion creator
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){Motion.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));}
        
    Cube.dimensions = Dimensions;
    Cube.colour = Colour;
    Cube.sound = Sound;
    Cube.motion = Motion;
    
    
    Cubetracker.push(Cube);
    return Cube;

    }
```

Comment: Do all the cubes in the array have the exact same values ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in JavaScript, object are passed by reference, and because you create your `Cube` object only once, its reference is reused and that is why all the objects in `Cubetracker` are the same.

To resolve that issue, you just have to move the creation of `Cube` inside the function, so that each time the function is called, a new ref, thus a new object is created.

Your bellow code

```js
  Cube.dimensions = Dimensions;
  Cube.colour = Colour;
  Cube.sound = Sound;
  Cube.motion = Motion;
```

Updated all the element in `Cubetracker`, because they all had the same ref.

Here is the solution:

```js
   
    
//History of cubes generated for n-back comparison    
var Cubetracker = [];

var rp, nb, sp;
rp = document.getElementById("rp").value;
nb = document.getElementById("nb").value;
sp = document.getElementById("sp").value;

//Takes inputs from screen 
var game_settings = {
  "reps": rp,
  "nback": nb,
  "speed": sp
};



function Cubegenerator() {

  var Cube = {
    "dimensions":"1",
    "colour":"2",
    "sound":"3",
    "motion":"4"}; 

  //Let's try encapsulating this within another function for ease of use

  function Repeatprob(rprob) {
    var rc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (rprob >= rc) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  var rpyn = Repeatprob(game_settings["nback"]);

  if (Cubetracker.length - 1 > 0 && Cubetracker.length - game_settings["nback"] > 0 && rpyn == true) {
    alert("You can take the cube from Cubetracker as a repeat cube");
    var rCube = Cubetracker.length - game_settings["nback"];
    var reCube = Cubetracker[rCube];
    Cubetracker.push(reCube);
    return reCube;
  }


  //var Cubetrl = (Cubetracker.length) - //1; 
  //if (Cubetrl - game_settings["nback"] > 0){
  //    var prci = (Cubetracker.length-1) - game_settings["nback"];
  //    var lastc = Cubetracker[prci];
  //    Cubetracker.push(lastc);
  //    return Cubetracker[lastc];
  //                }}

  var Dimensions = [];
  //dimensions creator
  var z_pos = "";
  var z_seed = "";
  var defzpos = 50;

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Dimensions.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) - (Math.random() * 300)))
  }

  for (i = 0; i < Dimensions.length; i++) {
    var ni = (Dimensions[i]).toString();
    ni += "px";
    Dimensions[i] = ni;
  }
  var z_seed = Math.floor(defzpos * Math.random(1, 10));
  var z_seed = z_seed.toString() + "px";
  var z_pos = [z_seed, z_seed];

  Dimensions.push(z_pos);


  var Colour = [];
  var rbgco = "";
  //dimensions creator
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Colour.push(Math.floor(Math.random(1, 10) * 256));
  }
  var rgbco = Colour.toString();
  var rgbco = "RGB(" + rgbco + ")";
  Colour = rgbco;


  var Sound = [];
  //sound creator
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    Sound.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
  }

  var Motion = [];
  //motion creator
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Motion.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }

  Cube.dimensions = Dimensions;
  Cube.colour = Colour;
  Cube.sound = Sound;
  Cube.motion = Motion;


  Cubetracker.push(Cube);
  console.log("Cubetracker", JSON.stringify(Cubetracker))
  return Cube;

}
```

```html
<input id="rp" type="text" value="1" />
<input id="nb" type="text" value="2" />
<input id="sp" type="text" value="3" />
<button onclick="Cubegenerator()">Generate a cube</button>
```

Comment: Thank you David! Look forward to implementing this now